# Same prediction for different hyperparameter in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, hyperparameters

I'm trying to perform a hyperparameter optimization on a neural net, but as soon as I try a larger number of hidden layers, my neural network will always predict the same output, so my list of (negative) losses looks like:

```
-0.789302627913455
-0.789302627913455
-0.789302627913455
-1
-0.789302627913455
-0.789302627913455
-1
-0.789302627913455
-0.789302627913455
-0.789302627913455
```

this is my neural net:

```
def nn(learningRate, layers, neurons, dropoutIn, dropoutHidden, miniBatch, activationFun, epoch):
x_data = []
y_data = []
x_data_train = []
y_data_train = []
x_data_test = []
y_data_test = []


session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
K.set_session(sess)

x_data = np.loadtxt('../4nodes_demand_vector')
x_data = x_data - x_data.min()
x_data = x_data / x_data.max() * 2
x_data = x_data - 1
y_data = np.loadtxt('../4nodes_vlink_vector')

input_dim = x_data.shape[1]
output_dim = y_data.shape[1]

split_ratio = 0.75
number_of_samples = x_data.shape[0]

# train data
x_data_train = x_data[:int(number_of_samples*split_ratio), ]
y_data_train = y_data[:int(number_of_samples*split_ratio), ]

# test data
x_data_test = x_data[int(number_of_samples*split_ratio):, ]
y_data_test = y_data[int(number_of_samples*split_ratio):, ]

adam = Adam(lr=learningRate)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dropout(dropoutIn, input_shape=(input_dim,)))
model.add(Dense(units=neurons, input_shape=(input_dim,), kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
for i in range(layers-1):
    model.add(Dropout(dropoutHidden))
    model.add(Dense(units=neurons, activation=activationFun, kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(Dense(units=output_dim, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer=adam)
model.fit(x_data_train, y_data_train, batch_size=miniBatch, validation_split=0.1, epochs=epoch, verbose=2)

predict = model.predict(x_data_test)
round_predict = np.round(predict)

correct = np.sum(np.all(round_predict == y_data_test, axis=1))
number_of_test_data = x_data_test.shape[0]
loss = -1.0 + (correct / float(number_of_test_data))
print("Loss: ", loss)

return loss
```

The neural net is trained on (unfortunately) private data, with 12 input neurons and 12 output neurons and I have 43000 data samples.
The idea of setting kernel_constraint to maxnorm(3) came from http://jmlr.org/papers/v15/srivastava14a.html as I was running in several NaN problems.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is from 2 years ago, but...

My guess is that the problem is because you are using a final activation of 'sigmoid' (typical for classification) with a loss function of 'mean_squared_error' (a regression loss)

Based on the final loss calculation it looks like you are trying to do a binary classification. So maybe try changing the loss function to binary crossentropy.